# Can I inoculate crabapple tree logs with mushroom plugs?

Tags: fruit-trees, mushrooms

My wife and I are interested in setting up a bit of a stumpery as a feature in the garden and a friend of ours has a crabapple tree he wants me to remove from his property. I was wondering if it was acceptable or effective to use crabapple wood as a growing medium for oyster/shiitake mushrooms, effectively killing two birds with one stone.

I searched for this online, and couldn't find anything yay or nay other than some people worried their trees are unhealthy because they're growing mushrooms from their trunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: yes.

Long answer:

- Turkey Tails-grow on anything except maybe black locust
- Wine Caps-grow on a lot of things
- Artist Conk - apparently:
  [Mushrooms on crab apple tree trunk](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29535/mushrooms-on-crab-apple-tree-trunk)
- others - they grow on things also, and some may grow on crab apple
  wood

Answer (score 1):

Fruit tree wood is not usually recommended for grooving mushrooms. I myself have never tried it but I do not see any harm in trying it out. Should probably try mushrooms recommended by black thumb. Your success is probably more dependent on how much care will you take in providing all other conditions like moisture, and defend against other mushrooms. Good luck!